# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven, deployment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Deploy Maven project on tomcat in eclipse SEVERE: A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976791/how-to-deploy-maven-project-on-tomcat-in-eclipse-severe-a-child-container-faile)

Hello I am new to Maven and just pulled down a project from an SVN repository, it was in a good working state during its last reversion. It is using spring + hibernate + jsf, and is being deployed on a tomcat server. I am getting the following error and was not sure what the problem is and am very lost. Any direction at all would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Dev\eclipse;;.
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:18 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:cepis' did not find a matching property.
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:18 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context/Logger'.
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 917 ms
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Aug 16, 2012 9:18:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cepis]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cepis]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.getDeclaredFields(WebAnnotationSet.java:452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:381)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    ... 21 more

Aug 16, 2012 9:18:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:782)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more

Aug 16, 2012 9:18:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Aug 16, 2012 9:18:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 695 ms
```

Thanks again in advance!!

EDIT:

SOLVED:

This may or may not be useful to others, but keep in mind I am new to Maven, turns out I was missing Maven Dependencies in the Deployment Assembly.

This was added by right clicking on the project in Eclipse.

->Properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add --> and then selected Maven Dependencies.

Comment: I am useing the latest version of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, (Juno)

Comment: In `Eclipse` have u used `Run as -> Run on server`?

Comment: Yes I have used this before, what I was forgetting was to add Maven Dependencies in the Deployment Assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is failing to load Springs jar files.

First approach:

- Make sure you have `m2eclipse` plugin installed
- Import the project as `maven project`
- Change projects facet to `Dynamic web project`
- [Add maven dependency for deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083501/maven-dependencies-not-visible-in-web-inf-lib)
- Now it should start using `Run as -> Run on server`

---

Second approach:

If above does not work, you will have to change `server.xml` of tomcat. Point it to `target``s `snapshot folder`. It will be something like below

```
<Context
  docBase="/path/to/target/cepis/snapshot/folder" 
  path="/cepis"
  reloadable="true" />
```

Instead of

```
<Context
  docBase="cepis"
  path="/cepis"
  reloadable="true"
  source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:cepis"/>
```

Now just start tomcat from eclipse. This approach always works for any web application.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I had already done the above "first approach" items, what I was forgetting was to add Maven Dependencies in the Deployment Assembly.

Comment: yes, updated the answer, though pointed by you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try refreshing all of your projects in Eclipse.  After that, make sure you "clean" the server state before starting it.  If its throwing NoClassDefFound errors, from my experience that means it can't find the files it needs.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was forgetting was to add Maven Dependencies in the Deployment Assembly.

Comment: That usually does it also. :)